# Extended screen with wayland Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, wayland

logged in with a wayland session, it is impossible to change the position of the external screen connected through HDMI.
When I move the screen image from right to left to be aligned with the physical position of the secondary screen on the left side of my laptop, the session close up when I hit the Apply button. And no change is done when I log in again.
It worked perfectly with Ubuntu 21.10, and it still works with XOrg session and Ubuntu 22.04.
Is there a CLI turn around, or is it a bug thus I must wait for the update ?